# SQL: Querying several tables, only most recent result from one, and all results from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of tables and I am trying to pull out data from many of them in one query.  I've worked out how to successfully use `LEFT JOIN` to pull in related data from other tables, with a common ID.

With this query I'm trying to do get data for each contact in our ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA table.

Firstly, I am trying to find their most recent meeting in the `ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S.DATE_OF_MEETING` (this is be stored as a timestamp, so looking for the largest timestamp only) - I am not getting the correct result, am I using the `MAX` function correctly?

Secondly, I want to get all records in the `ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS` for that `ASSOCIATE_ID`.  The right join doesn't seem to be pulling this in either?

Can anyone help?  Feel like I'm so close to getting the result for this, but this is really bugging me!

```
SELECT *, 
        ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.ASSOCIATE_ID as ABG_ASSOCIATE_ID,
            ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.NAME_KNOWN_AS as ABG_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
        ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.LAST_NAME as ABG_LAST_NAME, 
        USERS.NAME_KNOWN_AS as USERS_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
        USERS.LAST_NAME as USERS_LAST_NAME, 
        MAX(ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S.DATE_OF_MEETING)
    FROM ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA
 LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S
        ON ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.ASSOCIATE_ID = ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S.ASSOCIATE_ID
 LEFT JOIN LIST_OF_UNIVERSITIES
        ON ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.UNIVERSITY = LIST_OF_UNIVERSITIES.ID
 LEFT JOIN USERS
        ON ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.PROGRAMME_COORDINATOR = USERS.ID
 RIGHT JOIN ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS
        ON ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA.ASSOCIATE_ID = ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS.ASSOCIATE_ID
  GROUP BY ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S.ASSOCIATE_ID
  ORDER BY `ABG_NAME_KNOWN_AS` ASC
```

Many thanks in advance for any help or pointers that you can give...

Comment: Hi @Sebas, yes this is to use PHP to calculate an average based on the time between a completed action step and a deadline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your query. The first step for me was to reformat it to make it more readable (very important if you spend time on a query, you don't need any kind of overhead).

After that, I reviewed the logic and came to 2 conclusions:

- you don't need a right join
- your grouping algorithm was not quite correct.

Please have a look to this query and tell me if there's something missing:

```
SELECT 
    abg.ASSOCIATE_ID as ABG_ASSOCIATE_ID,
    abg.NAME_KNOWN_AS as ABG_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
    abg.LAST_NAME as ABG_LAST_NAME, 
    u.NAME_KNOWN_AS as USERS_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
    u.LAST_NAME as USERS_LAST_NAME, 
    t.lastmeeting
FROM ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA abg 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                abg.ASSOCIATE_ID as id,
                MAX(a1s.DATE_OF_MEETING) AS lastmeeting
            FROM ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA abg
                LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S a1s ON abg.ASSOCIATE_ID = a1s.ASSOCIATE_ID
            GROUP BY abg.ASSOCIATE_ID
            ) t ON t.id = abg.ASSOCIATE_ID
        LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS aas ON abg.ASSOCIATE_ID = aas.ASSOCIATE_ID
        LEFT JOIN USERS u ON abg.PROGRAMME_COORDINATOR = u.ID
ORDER BY abg.NAME_KNOWN_AS
```

I try to not use the permissiveness of mysql in regards to its `group by` function (mysql allows you to get away with a group by instruction not including all the selected fields), and stick to standards. But then it is necessary to make a subquery (see the `t` alias) precalculating the MAX(DATE) for each associate, to later join it back with the main recordset.

Cheers.

PS: you may add again the join with the universities, I skipped it to isolate the problem only.

PPS: to reflect your comment, I built this query:

```
SELECT 
    abg.ASSOCIATE_ID as ABG_ASSOCIATE_ID,
    abg.NAME_KNOWN_AS as ABG_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
    abg.LAST_NAME as ABG_LAST_NAME, 
    u.NAME_KNOWN_AS as USERS_NAME_KNOWN_AS, 
    u.LAST_NAME as USERS_LAST_NAME, 
    t.lastmeeting,
    t2.av AS averagetimedue
FROM ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA abg 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                abg.ASSOCIATE_ID as id,
                MAX(a1s.DATE_OF_MEETING) AS lastmeeting
            FROM ASSOCIATES_BACKGROUND_DATA abg
                LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATES_1_TO_1S a1s ON abg.ASSOCIATE_ID = a1s.ASSOCIATE_ID
            GROUP BY abg.ASSOCIATE_ID
            ) t ON t.id = abg.ASSOCIATE_ID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                (AVG(DATE_DUE)+AVG(DATE_COMPLETED))/2 AS av,
                ASSOCIATE_ID
            FROM ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS
            GROUP BY ASSOCIATE_ID
            ) t2 ON abg.ASSOCIATE_ID = t2.ASSOCIATE_ID
        LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATES_ACTION_STEPS aas ON abg.ASSOCIATE_ID = aas.ASSOCIATE_ID
        LEFT JOIN USERS u ON abg.PROGRAMME_COORDINATOR = u.ID
ORDER BY abg.NAME_KNOWN_AS
```

I'm not sure of your definition of `average time between DATE_DUE and DATE_COMPLETED` though.

Comment: Thanks so much @Sebas, this is really great!  Do you know if it is possible to get the average time between DATE_DUE and DATE_COMPLETED out of all the results for each Associate ID in the Action steps table?  Or should I do this with PHP?  Really need to learn more SQL for this type of thing!  Thanks again for your help, much appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi @Sebas, thanks again for your extra query!  I'm not sure that it does exactly what we're looking for though.  Is there a way to contact you for freelance work to help with this?  There are a couple extra things that we would like to pull out of this query too...

Comment: I couldn't see an email address, although your linkedin profile is there, but I don't have a premium linkedin account to get in touch that way.  Would be great to speak about this asap, if you're available to help?

Comment: Thanks, about to email